# File share mode in WinRT

Tags: logging, file-io, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have two processes writing the same file. It’s a log file BTW, the access is synchronized with a named mutex.

How do I make StorageFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync pass FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE to the underlying CreateFile2 WinAPI it likely uses from kernelbase.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s impossible.

The workaround — implement your own FileStream class using unmanaged interop. That’s relatively simple, mine is under 4 pages of code.

Here’s the imports you'll need for that:

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    const string file121 = "api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-1.dll";
    const string handle110 = "api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll";

    [DllImport( file121, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true )]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile2( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string filename,
        FileAccess dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, IntPtr pCreateExParams );

    [DllImport( handle110, SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    internal static extern bool CloseHandle( IntPtr handle );

    [DllImport( file121, SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandleEx( SafeFileHandle handle, FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS FileInformationClass, out FILE_STANDARD_INFO lpFileInformation, int dwBufferSize );

    internal static FILE_STANDARD_INFO GetFileStandardInfo( SafeFileHandle handle )
    {
        FILE_STANDARD_INFO fsi;
        if( !GetFileInformationByHandleEx( handle, FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS.FileStandardInfo, out fsi, Marshal.SizeOf<FILE_STANDARD_INFO>() ) )
            throw new COMException( "GetFileInformationByHandleEx failed.", Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error() );
        return fsi;
    }

    [DllImport( file121, SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    internal static extern bool SetFilePointerEx( SafeFileHandle handle, long liDistanceToMove, out long lpNewFilePointer, SeekOrigin dwMoveMethod );

    [DllImport( file121, SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    internal static extern bool SetFilePointerEx( SafeFileHandle handle, long liDistanceToMove, IntPtr lpNewFilePointer, SeekOrigin dwMoveMethod );

    [DllImport( file121, SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    internal static extern bool FlushFileBuffers( SafeFileHandle handle );

    [DllImport( file121, SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    internal static extern unsafe bool ReadFile( SafeFileHandle hFile, byte* lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped );

    [DllImport( file121, SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    internal static extern unsafe bool SetEndOfFile( SafeFileHandle hFile );

    [ DllImport( file121, SetLastError = true )]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
    internal static extern unsafe bool WriteFile( SafeFileHandle hFile, byte* lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten, IntPtr lpOverlapped ); }
```

You'll also need structures/enums/SafeFileHandle, but unlike imports, those are easy to copy-paste, e.g. from [CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx).